# how can i retrieve the child table data from master table in a string value

Tags: mysql

This is the master table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_film` (

  `film_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `film_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `film_cat` varchar(30) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `film_plot` longtext,
  `film_release_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `film_post_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `film_type` enum('Movie','Tv') CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT 'Movie',
  `film_feature` enum('Y','N') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `film_status` enum('ACTIVE','INACTIVE') CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE',
  `film_modify` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `film_link_value` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `film_post_link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=21435 ;
```

This the child table through which I map between the above gf_film table and lowest gf_actor table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_film_actor` (

  `film_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `actor_id` int(20) NOT NULL,

  KEY `film_id` (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This another table from which I have to retrieve the actor name:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_actor` (

  `actor_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `actor_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actor_desc` longtext CHARACTER SET latin1,

  PRIMARY KEY (`actor_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `actor_name` (`actor_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=60963 ;
```

And this the schema for `gf_film_poster`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gf_film_poster` (

  `film_id` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `website_poster_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `original_poster_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `default_poster_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'noposter.gif',

  UNIQUE KEY `film_id` (`film_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

After executing this query:

```
SELECT gf_film.film_id                                 ,
       film_name                                       ,
       DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%d') AS DATE     ,
       DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%m') AS month_ori,
       DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%M') AS MONTH    ,
       DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%Y') AS YEAR     ,
       film_release_date                               ,
       film_feature                                    ,
       film_modify                                     ,
       film_post_link                                  ,
       website_poster_url
FROM   gf_film
       LEFT JOIN gf_film_poster
       ON     gf_film.film_id=gf_film_poster.film_id
```

I am getting these results from database:

```
film_id,film_name,date,month_ori,month,year,film_release_date,
 film_feature,film_modify,film_post_link,website_poster_url
```

I need another column which contain the actors name and actor_id in one row related to each movies by joing the above query with gf_actor and gf_film_actor.

Comment: What's the schema of the gf_film_poster table?

Comment: is it one actor per film?  If not, do you want one actor per row returned, with other fields duplicated, or all actors on one row somehow?

Comment: no its no. of actors per film so i can find the actors by using other query instead of that i need one query to return all the filds including the actors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   gf_film.film_id                                 ,
         film_name                                       ,
         DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%d') AS DATE     ,
         DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%m') AS month_ori,
         DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%M') AS MONTH    ,
         DATE_FORMAT(film_release_date,'%Y') AS YEAR     ,
         film_release_date                               ,
         film_feature                                    ,
         film_modify                                     ,
         film_post_link                                  ,
         website_poster_url                              ,
         group_concat(gf_actor.actor_name) AS actors
FROM     gf_film
         LEFT JOIN gf_film_poster
         ON       gf_film.film_id=gf_film_poster.film_id
         LEFT JOIN gf_film_actor
         ON       gf_film_actor.film_id = gf_film.film_id
         LEFT JOIN gf_actor
         ON       gf_film_actor.actor_id = gf_actor.actor_id
GROUP BY gf_film.film_id
```

Comment: Thanx this query gives me perfect result what i need.

Comment: You add the group_concat with my query so could you tell me my query is properly optimized or not.